# How do I center each element with the element above it?

Tags: html, css, web

I have attached the HTML and CSS I have so far but I am new to front end so I'm not sure what the best approach is.

I just want each text element to be aligned with the respective numbers underneath them.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 50px;
}

ul {
    text-align: justify;
}
ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
}
li1 {
 font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #929292;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-right: 13em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.25em;
}

li2 {
 font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #929292;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-right: 13em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> REALSURF</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="realsurfcss.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:300,400,800" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
   <body>
      
      <h1>
      REALSURF
      </h1>
      
      <ul>
      <li1>Wind</li1>
      <li1>Wave Height</li1>
      <li1>Tide</li1>
      </ul>
   
      <ul>
      <li2>6</li2>
      <li2>3-4</li2>
      <li2>1.8^</li2>
      </ul>

   </body>
</html>
```

[image: For example: In the image I would like the left "text" to be center aligned with the 5, the center "text" centered with the 1-2, and the right "text" to be centered with the 8.]

Comment: And as the web page shrinks/ grows they stay center aligned with their respective elements

Comment: Do you wanna add the CSS as well?

Comment: And there's no `<li1>` or `<li2>` tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, wrap each columns of elements in the same block and set it's property *text-align* to *center* in CSS.

Here is an approach using CSS's flex (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Text<br />Number</div>
    <div class="column">Text<br />Number</div>
    <div class="column">Text<br />Number</div>
</div>
```

---

You can also do that with tables, take a look:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Text<br/>Number</td>
  <td>Text<br/>Number</td>
  <td>Text<br/>Number</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

You asked about styling of each rows, all you need to do is wrap each row in each element like below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: red;
}
.number {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
        <div class="number">Number</div>
    </div>            
    <div class="column">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
        <div class="number">Number</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
        <div class="number">Number</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: How would I apply different CSS styling to the "text" and "number"s?

Comment: @DavidOwens I edited my answer and added an example on how to do that at the end. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest with Ruby annotations, but it'll only work in more modern browsers:

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ruby>
  5<rp>(</rp><rt>text</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
<ruby>
  1-2<rp>(</rp><rt>text</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
<ruby>
  8<rp>(</rp><rt>text</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
```

Comment: Wow... What about the browser support and what's this thing?

Comment: [MDN page on `<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby); and [support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ruby).

Answer (score 0):

using pseudo element `after` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9m4u19q/)

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 90px;
}

li:before{
  content: 'text';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```